# How to make Swing Checkbox in list with different background color

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Lets start with saying Im not very knowledgeable with Swing. But I have a regular JTable where I have various columns, some of which is Booleans which gets translated to checkboxes. And as you can see in the image below, their background is pure white, and doesnt follow the "alternative" coloring as the other fields (Double and Strings). Any clue on what is happening here is appreciated.

[image: Example of Swing application with checkboxes with only white backgrounds]

Comment: You need to use custom `TableCellRenderer`, here is [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer).

Comment: Are you using the default renderer or a custom renderer? Try your code using the default LAF, instead of Nimbus to see what happens.

Comment: change opacity for Nimbus

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments guys. It led me straight right! So I googled some custom renderer for Nimbus and checkboxes and found this which did exactly that I wanted.

https://code.google.com/p/jsparklines/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/no/uib/jsparklines/extra/NimbusCheckBoxRenderer.java?r=77

Thanks again